# Get all attribute values of elements in XDocuments

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I would like to get all attribute values of the same elements in an `XDocument`

e.g.

```
   <guideline >
     <title>hello world</title>
     <breadcrumb>    
      <ulink url="1.htm">hello world</ulink>     
     </breadcrumb>
     <breadcrumb>    
       <ulink url="2.htm">Chronic Care</ulink>      
     </breadcrumb>
     <breadcrumb>    
       <ulink url="3.htm">hello world</ulink>
       <emphasis role="bold"> &gt;</emphasis>
       <ulink url="4.htm">hello world</ulink>      
     </breadcrumb>
     <breadcrumb>          
      <ulink url="5.htm">hello world</ulink>
      <emphasis role="bold"> &gt;</emphasis>
      <ulink url="8.htm">hello world</ulink>    
      </breadcrumb>
      <breadcrumb>            
        <ulink url="6.htm">hello world</ulink>
        <emphasis role="bold"> &gt;</emphasis>
        <ulink url="7.htm">hello world</ulink>            
      </breadcrumb>
  </guideline>
```

If I have this kind of xml, I want all url values of `<ulink>` without looping through   each element.

I have tried this but not working for me:

```
var urls = from vector in this.root.Descendants(xmlns + "ulink") 
           select  vector.Attribute("url").Value;
```

Comment: are you getting a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: does `from vector in this.root.Descendants(xmlns + "ulink") ` work for getting the elements?

Comment: No exception, it just doesn't have any value. I just tried, this.root.Descendants(xmlns + "ulink") but this neither return a value

Comment: In that case, I think that there's likely something wrong with your namespace.  maybe it's mis-spelled

Comment: Thanks Man you can be right, I was trying to parse xmldocument to XDocument. and play with xdocument instead. May be i should keep using xmldocument.

Comment: does your xml even have a namespace? if it doesn't you don't need the `xmlns

Comment: No, It doesnt have. Let me check with out the name space

Comment: Thanks Buddy, this is working: from vector in xdoc.Descendants("ulink") select vector.Attribute("url"); You were right i didnt need the name space. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

since you've comfirmed that your xml doesn't have any namespaces in it, you can do away with that `xmlns`, and then it should work.

```
var urls = from vector in this.root.Descendants("ulink") 
           select  vector.Attribute("url").Value;
```